# Energy of a three-dimensional system

Tags: mesoscopic-physics

The energy of a three-dimensional system of dimensions $L_x$, $L_y$, $L_z$, is given by,
$$\varepsilon\left(n_{x}, n_{y}, n_{z}\right)=\frac{\hbar}{2 m}\left[\left(\frac{\pi n_{x}}{L_{x}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\pi n_{y}}{L_{y}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\pi n_{z}}{L_{z}}\right)^{2}\right].$$

Now, if we go into a limit where $L_x$ and $L_y$ become so small that they become comparable to the Fermi energy, we can consider the systems as two-dimensional or one-dimensional. For example, $L_{x}<\lambda_{F} \ll L_{y}<L_{z}$, the system can be approximated as two-dimensional. In such cases, when one dimension is so small, is the energy of the system dominated by the energy along that axis, which is $L_x$ in this case?